# How to make a moving platform rotate depending on its path, in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make floating platforms that follow the stream of water and its rotation.
To do that I put waypoints on the vertices of the water.
I know how to make the platform go from one another but I don't know how to change the platform rotation so it seems that it's floating on the water.

(I also don't know how to make the player follow the platform without squeezing when it rotates, but that's a problem for another time)

I tried some stuff but it didn't turn out like i wanted.
Maybe I can measure the angle between two points/make the platform face the next point, and then add a float to the angle I find using these methods.
Maybe I can even do it through a rigidbody, I don't know what is the easiest to do.

here is my code for the platform :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FloatingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private WaypointPath _waypointPath;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed;

    private int _targetWaypointIndex;

    private Transform _previousWaypoint;
    private Transform _targetWaypoint;

    private float _timeToWaypoint;
    private float _elapsedTime;
    
    void Start()
    {
        TargetNextWaypoint();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        float elapsedPercentage = _elapsedTime / _timeToWaypoint;
        elapsedPercentage = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, elapsedPercentage);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_previousWaypoint.position, _targetWaypoint.position, elapsedPercentage);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(_previousWaypoint.rotation, _targetWaypoint.rotation, elapsedPercentage);

        if (elapsedPercentage >= 1)
        {
            TargetNextWaypoint();
        }
    }

    private void TargetNextWaypoint()
    {
        _previousWaypoint = _waypointPath.GetWaypoint(_targetWaypointIndex);
        _targetWaypointIndex = _waypointPath.GetNextWaypointIndex(_targetWaypointIndex);
        _targetWaypoint = _waypointPath.GetWaypoint(_targetWaypointIndex);

        _elapsedTime = 0;

        float distanceToWaypoint = Vector3.Distance(_previousWaypoint.position, _targetWaypoint.position);
        _timeToWaypoint = distanceToWaypoint / _speed;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        other.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        other.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the waypoints :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform GetWaypoint(int waypointIndex)
    {
        return transform.GetChild(waypointIndex);
    }

    public int GetNextWaypointIndex(int currentWaypointIndex)
    {
        int nextWaypointIndex = currentWaypointIndex + 1;

        if (nextWaypointIndex == transform.childCount)
        {
            nextWaypointIndex = 0;
        }

        return nextWaypointIndex;
    }
}
```

PS : Sorry for my bad english, it's not my foreign language.

Comment: you already seem to interpolate the rotation in `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(_previousWaypoint.rotation, _targetWaypoint.rotation, elapsedPercentage);` ... sounds like instead / additionally you want some rotation around Z while rotating the object around Y (["tilt sway rotation"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45ssV6CEgoU))